Peltier cooler driving circuit
To prevent closing as duplicate immediately, there is the list of the most relevant questions:

How to drive a Peltier element?
Driving a Peltier w/ PWM or analog out
Driving a Peltier element with PWM
Peltier Driving Circuit

There are more, but neither provides a (complete) schematic for high-frequency PWM mode with filtering. Also, a lot of questions & answers suggest discrete gate drivers, I'm unsure why given that gate driving ICs are readily available. So, with all the info given on the topic, I've designed the circuit (using KiCad):

12 V is provided by a common ATX PSU. The gate driver is IRS44273LPBF, the Peltier cooler is TEC1-12710, the MOSFET is AO4410, diodes are Schottky SS54. The inductor was salvaged from a PSU years ago, the inductance is about 1 uH, the saturation current is unknown but should be enough. The PWM signal will be produced by a MCU. The simulation in Microcap 12 shows that everything should be well, however, there is no model for the AO4410, so IRLZ24NS was used instead.Are there any flaws in the design, and what improvements to the circuit can be suggested?

please add a link to the source of the image to your question... do not use a comment

@jsotola sorry, what link? It is the screenshot I've captured and uploaded.

then you must state that the circuit is your own design

Is a high frequency useful when you consider the thermal mass of the object to control the temperature of and the required temperature hysteresis? Maybe something that works at, say, 0.01 Hz would be as effective.

One suggestion: add temperature-sensing to the hot side of the Peltier cooler, either active (e.g., thermistor and controller), or just a thermal switch, to prevent damage from overheating.

D2 doesn't seem to do anything.

@AndrewMorton unfortunately, this will not work for liquid flow.

@DrMoishePippik or is it better to monitor current through the PE? Is there a point in measuring the heatsink's temperature? And it is likely not possible to measure the temperature inside the element.

@JohnDoty a negative voltage swing occurs during the on-switching of the mosfet, D2 is for clamping.

@AndrewMorton you seem to miss the point that peltiers are always less efficient when toggled on/off compared to an equivalent DC current.

@tobalt That was the entire point of me asking about the thermal system parameters. However, the OP has since commented that it's for a liquid flow system.

Why does it need clamping? You have C1 and PE1 pulling it up.

@JohnDoty because an LC circuit is oscillating when switched? The lowest voltage is about -7.5 V at the D2 cathode, if switched on "hard". My manual calculations are in a very good agreement with Microcap.

@Suthiro, why would you believe current has a direct relationship to the temperature of the hot side? Blocking heat flow from the hot side, or excessive heat input on the cold side, could raise the temp of the device to the point it is damaged.

@DrMoishePippik I would suppose that a large temperature difference between sides corresponds to a large thermopower. And the thermopower decreases the current through the element for given PWM parameters. But I see what you mean: no difference between sides, but very hot. It is worth thinking about. Thanks.

The selected MOSFET AO4410 is not the optimal choice in this context. Logic level FETs tend to have large gate capacitance but yor gate driver does not require a FET with that low threshold voltage.
Driving a 10 nF gate with 10 Ω at 1 MHz will introduce significant switching losses.
There are FETs with less than 2 nF gate capacitance and even lower on resistance < 3 mΩ available like e.g. BSC0502NSIATMA1.

Good point. I'll reconsider the choice of the FET. Thanks.

Decided to use 6.8 Ω gate resistor and IRF8714TRPBF. Thanks again.

Good choice, very fast FET.
